# QAbstractTableModel::insertRows appending new data to internal QList

Tags: c++, qt

I have following class, which represents record in data structure:

```
#ifndef UECONNECTEDCLIENTRECORD_H
#define UECONNECTEDCLIENTRECORD_H

#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QObject>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QString>

class UeConnectedClientRecord : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    /**
     * @brief m_ueClientName
     */
    QString m_ueClientName;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueClientAddress
     */
    QHostAddress m_ueClientAddress;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueClientPort
     */
    QString m_ueClientPort;

public:
    /**
     * @brief UeConnectedClientRecord
     * @param parent
     */
    explicit UeConnectedClientRecord(const QString& clientName=QString(),
                                     const QHostAddress& clientAddress=QHostAddress(),
                                     const QString& clientPort=QString());

    /**
     * @brief ueSetClientName
     * @param name
     */
    inline void ueSetClientName(const QString& name)
        { this->m_ueClientName=name; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetClientAddress
     * @param address
     */
    inline void ueSetClientAddress(const QHostAddress& address)
        { this->m_ueClientAddress=address; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetClientPort
     * @param port
     */
    inline void ueSetClientPort(const QString& port)
        { this->m_ueClientPort=port; }

    /**
     * @brief ueClientName
     * @return client name
     */
    inline const QString& ueClientName() const
        { return this->m_ueClientName; }

    /**
     * @brief ueClientAddress
     * @return client address
     */
    inline const QHostAddress& ueClientAddress() const
        { return this->m_ueClientAddress; }

    /**
     * @brief ueClientPort
     * @return client port
     */
    inline const QString& ueClientPort() const
        { return this->m_ueClientPort; }
};

#endif // UECONNECTEDCLIENTRECORD_H
```

which is used in subclassed [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#details):

```
#ifndef UECONNECTEDCLIENTSTABLEMODEL_H
#define UECONNECTEDCLIENTSTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QList>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QHash>
#include <QByteArray>

#include "ueconnectedclientrecord.h"

class UeConnectedClientsTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    /**
     * @brief m_ueConnectedClientData
     */
    QList<UeConnectedClientRecord*> m_ueConnectedClientData;

protected:
    /**
     * @brief ueSetConnectedClientData
     * @param clientData
     */
    inline void ueSetConnectedClientData(const QList<UeConnectedClientRecord*>& clientData)
        { this->m_ueConnectedClientData=clientData; }

public:
    /**
     * @brief UeConnectedClientsTableModel
     * @param parent
     */
    UeConnectedClientsTableModel(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR);

    /**
     * @brief ueConnectedClientData
     * @return connected client data
     */
    inline const QList<UeConnectedClientRecord*>& ueConnectedClientData() const
        { return this->m_ueConnectedClientData; }

    /**
     * @brief rowCount
     * @param parent
     * @return number of rows in model
     */
    inline int rowCount(const QModelIndex& /*parent*/) const
        { return this->ueConnectedClientData().size(); }

    /**
     * @brief columnCount
     * @return number of columns in model
     */
    inline int columnCount(const QModelIndex& /*parent*/) const
        { return 3; }

    /**
     * @brief data
     * @param index
     * @param role
     * @return data for index
     */
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index,
                  int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    /**
     * @brief roleNames
     * @return role names
     */
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    /**
     * @brief headerData
     * @param section
     * @param orientation
     * @param role
     * @return header data
     */
    QVariant headerData(int section,
                        Qt::Orientation orientation,
                        int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    /**
     * @brief insertRows
     * @param row
     * @param count
     * @param parent
     * @return true if the rows were successfully inserted; otherwise returns false
     */
    bool insertRows(int row,
                    int count,
                    const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex());

    /**
     * @brief removeRows
     * @param row
     * @param count
     * @param parent
     * @return true if the rows were successfully removed; otherwise returns false
     */
    bool removeRows(int row,
                    int count,
                    const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex());

public:
    /**
     * @brief ueRoleClientName
     */
    static const int ueRoleClientName=Qt::UserRole+1;

    /**
     * @brief ueRoleClientAddress
     */
    static const int ueRoleClientAddress=Qt::UserRole+2;

    /**
     * @brief ueRoleCllientPort
     */
    static const int ueRoleCllientPort=Qt::UserRole+3;
};

#endif // UECONNECTEDCLIENTSTABLEMODEL_H
```

and its implementation:

```
#include "ueconnectedclientstablemodel.h"

UeConnectedClientsTableModel::UeConnectedClientsTableModel(QObject* parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}   // constructor

QVariant UeConnectedClientsTableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index,
                                            int role) const
{
    switch(role)
    {
        case ueRoleClientName:
        {
            return this->ueConnectedClientData().at(index.row())->ueClientName();
        }   // case

        case ueRoleClientAddress:
        {
            return this->ueConnectedClientData().at(index.row())->ueClientAddress().toString();
        }   // case

        case ueRoleCllientPort:
        {
            return this->ueConnectedClientData().at(index.row())->ueClientPort().toInt();
        }   // case

        default:
        {
            return UeConnectedClientsTableModel::data(index,
                                                      role);
        }   // default
    }   // switch
}   // data

QHash<int, QByteArray> UeConnectedClientsTableModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

    const int roleClientName=UeConnectedClientsTableModel::ueRoleClientName;
    const int roleClientAddress=UeConnectedClientsTableModel::ueRoleClientAddress;
    const int roleCllientPort=UeConnectedClientsTableModel::ueRoleCllientPort;

    roles.insert(roleClientName,
                 "roleClientName");
    roles.insert(roleClientAddress,
                 "roleClientAddress");
    roles.insert(roleCllientPort,
                 "roleCllientPort");

    return roles;
}   // roleNames

QVariant UeConnectedClientsTableModel::headerData(int section,
                                                  Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                                  int role) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(orientation)

    if(role!=Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    switch(section)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            return tr("Client name");
        }   // case

        case 1:
        {
            return tr("Client address");
        }   // case

        case 2:
        {
            return tr("Client port");
        }   // case

        default:
        {
            return QVariant();
        }   // default
    }   // switch
}   // headerData

bool UeConnectedClientsTableModel::insertRows(int row,
                                              int count,
                                              const QModelIndex& parent)
{
    this->beginInsertRows(parent,
                          row,
                          row+count);

    for(int index=row; index<row+count; index++)
    {
        m_ueConnectedClientData.append(new UeConnectedClientRecord());
    }   // for

    this->endInsertRows();

    return true;
}   // insertRows

bool UeConnectedClientsTableModel::removeRows(int row,
                                              int count,
                                              const QModelIndex& parent)
{
    this->beginRemoveRows(parent,
                          row,
                          row+count);

    for(int index=row; index<row+count; index++)
    {
        m_ueConnectedClientData.removeLast();
    }   // for

    this->endRemoveRows();

    return true;
}   // removeRows
```

Now, how do I call `insertRows()` from code to insert new `UeConnectedClientRecord` with real data (not `new UeConnectedClientRecord()` - default constructor) to internal `QList`? I am asking the because I've searched accross internet to see examples and I've found [Qt Address Book Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html), however, [insertRows() from official docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) and [insertRows() from Address Book Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html) are declared differently:

- `bool QAbstractItemModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());` from [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows)
- `bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex()) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;` from [Address Book Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html)

Why?

Comment: `insertRows` functions are declared similar. Look carefully.

Comment: @liotXXl yes there are similar, ok, but it is at least misleading.

Comment: To insert "real" data to the model, Address Book Example has `AddressWidget::addEntry` that first calls `insertRows` to insert new, default constructed empty row to the model. Then, it next sets the data for the newly inserted row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation:

> If you implement your own model, you can reimplement this function if you want to support insertions. Alternatively, you can provide your own API for altering the data. In either case, you will need to call `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` to notify other components that the model has changed.

Way 1. Use `insertRows` + `setData`. Qt supposes that null-records are possible and that to add row is not to add data. As your internal list is a `Qlist` of pointers, you can insert `nullptr` there to prevent default constructor call. In this case you will need item check on each `data` call: if the item is `nullptr`, a default value should be returned.

Way 2. You can implement your own insert function. As far as I know, the `insertRows` function is not used by views and usually is called manually. But "usually" is not "always". For example, proxy models can use it.

Comment: @ilotXXl I've decided to go with **Way 1**, however, do I also need to reimplement `index()` method?

Comment: @KernelPanic I think no, `QAbstractTableModel` did it for you. Look at [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#details), Subclassing paragraph.